# DbContext throw already tracked entity but no entity tracked

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm developing a Xamarin App with a .NET 6 Web API. I use Entity Framework Core for my ORM to connect a SQL Server database.

I'm trying to update an entity of this class:

```cs
public class Customer 
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? IdMetier { get; set; }
    public int IdAdresseFacture { get; set; }
    public int? IdAdresseBl { get; set; }
 
    [ForeignKey("IdMeier")]
    public N17Metier? Metier { get; set; }
   
    [ForeignKey("IdAdresseFacture")]
    public Adress AdresseFacture { get; set; } = new Adress();
    
    [ForeignKey("IdAdresseBl")]
    public Adress? AdresseBl { get; set; } = new Adress();
}
```

My entry point to get the client is like :

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> GetClient(int idClient)
{
    var client = await _dbContext.N1Clients
                                 .Include(c => c.AdresseBl)
                                 .Include(c => c.AdresseFacture)
                                 .Include(c => c.Metier)
                                 .FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Id == idClient);

    return Ok(client);
}
```

And my update method is like :

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ModifyClient(int idClient, [FromBody] N1Client client)
{
    if (client is null)
        return BadRequest();

    if (idClient != client.IdCrm)
        return BadRequest();

    var entity = await _dbContext.N1Clients.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Id == idClient);

    if (entity is null)
        return NotFound();

    var isExist = await _dbContext.N1Clients.AnyAsync(c => c.Id == idClient);

    if (!isExist)
        return NotFound();

    client.DtMaj = DateTime.Now;

    _dbContext.Update(client);
    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken.None);

    return NoContent();
}
```

My `dbcontext` is set to a ServiceLifetime of scoped. So each time I make a request from my app a fresh `dbContext` is set (the way I understand it, it could be wrong).

When I make the two request GET and then PUT with Postman the workflow work very well and my entity is updated without any errors. But when I make the two requests from my Xamarin app I have an exception which tell me that an entity of type address with Id: 400 is already track and no other can be added.

I have tested to verify if the entity is being tracked with `_dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries()` but no entity is found.

Thanks for your help and sorry for my English, first post here, maybe I missed something.

**EDIT :**

This type of code throw the same exception :

```cs
_dbContext = new CRMContext();

var isExist = await _dbContext.N1Clients.AnyAsync(c => c.Id == idClient);
if (!isExist)
   return NotFound();

_dbContext.N1Clients.Update(client);
await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken.None);
```

At the beginning of the method the list of tracked entities is empty, but throw the exception already tracked entity with Id 400.

The most frustrating is that with Postman I do not have any errors, but from my app I have this exception. Does Postman works differently in calling the api than a C# HttpClient ?

**SOLUTION :**

My bad... It is obvious when I found where I made a mistake. My entity has others properties like a collection of a children :

```cs
public class Customer {
   //...
   public virtual IColection<Evenement> Events { get; set; }
}

public class Evenement {
   //...
   public Adress Adresse { get; set; }
}
```

But when I pass the customer to my method for update I don't clear the collection and my Events has the same `Adresse.Id` than the customer. So entity framework throw the correct exception. In Postman, all my collection was empty, so no errors...

Thanks for your help all.

Comment: Have you listed the current tracked entities?

Comment: i'm having this entity as well and it's really frustrating. especially when you assume that your DBContext is injected as a scoped services that should be discarded after every request
can i assume this is the same case for you? because if you'd use a singleton you could definitely run into problems.

Comment: Why are you sending the Client over the wire? You already have `idClient`.  And you are loading `entity`, just update that.

Comment: [Identity Resolution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/identity-resolution)

Comment: `var entity = ...FirstOrDefaultAsync` begins tracking entity. `_dbContext.Update` begins tracking entity with the same id.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov I have seen the documentation on Identity Resolution, but when I try their different methods it throw the exception. Even if I create a new DbContext at first and only call the `.AnyAsync()` it throw the exception...

Answer (score 0):

Why not using [.AsNoTracking()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbextensions.asnotracking?view=entity-framework-5.0.0) in your queries and manually tracking the entities you want to track?

e.g.:

```cs
// sample query
var query = dbContext.MyTable.AsNoTracking().Where(x=>x.Credits > 10);

// sample foreach so you can have a better understanding
foreach (var q in query) 
{
    if (q.IsAdmin && x.Credits < 1000)
    {
          q.Credits = 100000;
          // marks just this "q" object as Modified, 
          // the rest remains Unchanged (instead of NotTracked)
          dbContext.Entry(q).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
}

// only those Entries marked as Modified will be saved.
await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Sorry about the bad example (couldn't quickly figure out one to demonstrate

---

If you are really desperate and want to see all the changes to the tracked, you can override the SaveChanges/SaveChangesAsync method as follows:

```cs
   public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
    {
        foreach (var entityEntry in ChangeTracker.Entries())
        {
            switch (entityEntry.State)
            {
                case EntityState.Added:
                    Console.WriteLine($"{entityEntry.Entity.GetType().Name} added");
                    break;
                case EntityState.Modified:
                    Console.WriteLine($"{entityEntry.Entity.GetType().Name} modified");
                    break;
            }
        }
        await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
```

Comment: I have tried to use the `.AsNoTracking()` but it throw the exception. I will try to override the saveChanges method and I will tell you if it worked, thanks.

Comment: @Neibue it shouldn't throw an exception with AsNoTracking! What's the exception are you having?

Comment: It was generating the same exception. In fact, the DbContext was totally fine and clear, but like I said in my solution, it was a child entity which had a common IdAdresse therefore the exception was correct. I just cleared the property whan I was updating my entity. Thanks for your help